# How to read column names of Excel using LinqToExcel generated by EPPlus?

Tags: .net, excel, linq, epplus, linq-to-excel

I want to read the column names of an excel file generated using EPPlus with LinqToExcel. This is what I have done so far

```
var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelPath);
IQueryable<Row> excelSheetValues = from workingSheet in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select workingSheet;
string[] headerRow = excelFile.GetColumnNames(sheetName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Will the below foreach work for you? you could traverse through the start row, and start column and get the cell text (or set)

```
var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelPath);
IQueryable<Row> excelSheetValues = from workingSheet in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select workingSheet;
string[] headerRow = excelFile.GetColumnNames(sheetName).ToArray(); 
var ws = excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName);
foreach (var cell in ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Start.Row, ws.Dimension.Start.Column, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column]) 
    Console.WriteLine(cell.Text);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, when I'm retrieving all column names at headerRow. And I have to do something if column values is empty.So I cannot loop on everything @Krishna

Comment: where are you getting the error? excelFile.GetColumnNames(sheetName).ToArray(); on this line?

Comment: I'm not able to retrieve the values using Linq To Excel @Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Try this if column names is specified in the first row:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelPath);
var columnNames = excel.GetColumnNames(excel.GetWorksheetNames().FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```